# Banach Steinhaus theorem (uniformly boundnedness)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ a Banach space and $Y$ a normed vectorial space. Let $\{T_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}\subseteq B(X,Y)$.Then we have one of the conditions :

a) exist a generic set $G$ so that $\sup_{\alpha \in A}||T_{\alpha}x||=+\infty \quad\forall x \in G$

b) $\sup_{\alpha \in A}||T_{\alpha}||<\infty$

Can I replace the condition a) with

exists  $V_n$ open sets in $X$ so that  $\sup_{\alpha \in A}||T_{\alpha}x||=+\infty \quad\forall x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }V_n$?

I know that $G$ is a generic set if exist a succession $V_n$ of open and dense sets so that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }V_n\subseteq G$ and for Baire's theorem $G$ is dense in X

So if exist a generic set $G$ so that $\sup_{\alpha \in A}||T_{\alpha}x||=+\infty \quad\forall x \in G$ then (because $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }V_n\subseteq G$) $\forall x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }V_n \sup_{\alpha \in A}||T_{\alpha}x||=+\infty $?

It's right my argument?

Comment: what is the definition of a generic set?

Comment: a generic set is the supplementary of a set of first category